# $f'(f^{-1}(x))$. How do I take the derivative of this?

Tags: calculus, functions, trigonometry, inverse-function

I am told that $f'(f^{-1}(x))$ where $f(x) = \sin(x)$ and $f^{-1}(x) = \arcsin(x)$.

When I see $f'(f^{-1}(x))$, I instantly think of applying the chain rule since we have a composite of functions. However, my textbook does it differently; it does not apply the chain rule:

$f(x) = \sin(x)$

$\implies f'(x) = \cos(x)$

$\therefore f'(f^{-1}(x)) = f'(\arcsin(x)) = \cos(\arcsin(x))$.

I do not understand why the textbook does the above calculations instead of using the chain rule. I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to clarify this and explain the reasoning behind the decision.

Comment: You are not asked to find the derivative of the function $f'\circ f^{-1}$. You are asked to *determine* that function, given $f$ and $f^{-1}$.

Comment: You also are not "told that $f'(f^{-1}(x))$". Indeed that clause makes no grammatical sense: it is like saying "I am told that 4." You are told to *find* $f'(f^{-1}(x))$, or something like that. Pay closer attention to the English, not just the symbols, which do indeed involve a composition of functions.

Comment: @symplectomorphic thanks for the response. Can you please elaborate on your first answer? I am not entirely understanding what you're saying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reverse engineering from the solution given in the book, it is clear to me you misread the problem. The problem did not ask you to *differentiate* the function $f'(f^{-1}(x))$. The problem asked you to *find* (a formula for) $f'(f^{-1}(x))$.

You are right that the former problem requires the chain rule (and Sonnhard's answer shows you the answer to *that* question). But that is not the question you were asked, assuming the solution in the book is right.

To answer the question you *were* given, you just need to evaluate the function $f'(x)=\cos x$ at the inverse of $f$. These are exactly the steps your book follows. (One could go a step further and write $\cos(\arcsin x)$ as an algebraic function, $\sqrt{1-x^2}$, but that is another matter.)

Comment: What do you mean when you say, "find (a formula for) $f'(f^{-1}(x))"? I'm really struggling to understand because this seems like a simple derivatives problem.

Comment: @The Pointer: please copy and paste here **verbatim** exactly what the problem says to do. Or take a photo. If you do so I will be able to point out what you are failing to read.

Comment: For some further intuition: if I ask you for $f'(g(x))$ where $f(x)=\sin x$ and $g(x)=x^2$, do you understand that I'm only asking you to *find* the composite $f'\circ g$ rather than *take the derivative of* the composite $f'\circ g$? In this case $f'(x)=\cos x$, so $f'(g(x))$ is just $\cos(x^2)$. You are being asked to *calculate* a composite function, not *differentiate* one.

Comment: The derivative of $f'(g(x))$ is written $(f'(g(x))'$ and by the chain rule becomes $f''(g(x))g'(x)$. That isn't what you want. You want just $f'(g(x))$, not $(f'(g(x))'$.

Comment: It is a proof for $\arcsin'(x) = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1 - x^2}}$. It gives $\arcsin'(x) = f^{-1}'(x)$ $= \dfrac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(x))}$ $= \dfrac{1}{\sin'(arcsin(x))}$ $= \dfrac{1}{\cos(arcsin(x))}$ and so on ...

Comment: I apologise, but I can't find the MathJax error for the above comment.

Comment: @The Pointer: It doesn't matter. Read my comments. You are making an extremely elementary error.

Comment: Your additional comments have clarified my misunderstanding. Thank you very much for the assistance; I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

it is just the chain rule
$$f''(f^{-1}(x))\cdot (f^{-1}(x))'$$